# Flutter: close search bar without contacts

Tags: flutter

I'm using this Flutter functionality:

```
/// Closes the search page and returns to the underlying route.
  ///
  /// The value provided for `result` is used as the return value of the call
  /// to [showSearch] that launched the search initially.
  void close(BuildContext context, T result) {
    _currentBody = null;
    _focusNode?.unfocus();
    Navigator.of(context)
      ..popUntil((Route<dynamic> route) => route == _route)
      ..pop(result);
  }
```

NOTE: that's from Flutter package, I cannot change it

Before non-null update I had this:

```
close(context, null);
```

but now it's failing because of this:

> The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Contact'.

What do I need to pass if I only need to close it without passing any contact?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
  void close(BuildContext context, T? result) {
    _currentBody = null;
    _focusNode?.unfocus();
    Navigator.of(context)
      ..popUntil((Route<dynamic> route) => route == _route)
      ..pop(result);
  }
```

But I believe the problem is occuring somewhere else where a variable of type Contact is required. You should be able to fix it by making it ok for the variable to be null using a ?

I have not shifted to null safety yet but I believe a good way to use null could be a custom string declared in every file like

```
null1 = 'This is an intricate null string which cant be copied'
```

and then you can treat it like null

Read more about null safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Comment: That close function is the original Flutter one. I can modify it but it's inside the packages folder